# Multiple Entity Types in One Collection with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

### Context

In my application, I have a few subclasses (Admin, Parent, Chaperone) that all extend a given superclass (Contactable). I've seperated admin, parent, and chaperone users into their own tables.

### Problem

I'm trying to construct a group chat between the three user types where the topic is a given child of the parent. I have a groupchat entity which uses the child id as a PK, and it is to contain a collection of messages.

What I'd like to do is have a @OneToMany collection of messages in the groupchat entity, where each message is mapped to either a chaperone, parent, or admin.

### Possible Solutions

I could have three collections in the GroupChat entity for messages from each user type. The messages from each user type would also be their own entity (ParentMessage, ChaperoneMessage...). I would then zip the messages from each collection on request to show messages from all user types in order of time.

I don't like that solution though.

Is there a way to make use of generics such that I can have a single Message entity, and a single collection in group chat of these messages, and have jpa handle the rest? (wishful thinking, but don't know if you don't ask!)

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't realise the hibernate docs were that extensive! I've used mapped superclasses in the application and so I can't do what I want to do, but thank you for pointing me towards that.

Comment: As an alternative, you could try using hibernate's `@Any`. Not sure if it works for completely unrelated entities, though

Comment: @crizzis seems to be an sql antipattern, but good to be aware of.